# What should one do before submitting a paper?

Tags: soft-question, journals, advice

Assume I just wrote a paper. Now I would like to publish it in a journal.

What kind of things I should do before its submission?
Should I first give a few talks at seminars or conferences? Upload to arxiv? Send to a few experts?

What is the best algorithm?

Comment: here is an [overview](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/reu2009/publishing.pdf) of the process --- main message: _Don’t try anything without advice and guidance from your advisor or an experienced mathematician familiar with your work._

Comment: Perhaps academia.SE would be a better fit? There are a number of experienced mathematicians active there.

Comment: Go back and check through it a second and then a third time for typos. Too many experienced mathematicians skip these steps.

Comment: Also, go back and check through it for logical gaps and outright errors. Do a thorough literature search to make sure you haven't been beaten to it by Euler or Erdos or Tom Lehrer ("I have a friend in Minsk....").

Comment: Another general advice, hence only a comment: After you *think* you have completed your paper, take a break from it / do something else for a week or two, or three, then get back to it to reread it with a fresher/outside perspective. You will be surprised how many things you are going to notice and will be wanting to fix/edit/improve.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I looked at academia.SE several times in the past, and I found the amount of pointless comments and answers (pointless because the site is not maths-specific and a lot of people feel that they should offer their opinion even if it is not relevant) very frustrating. So I totally understand at least one reason to post this question on MO.

Comment: This depends greatly from person to person. Some just cross their fingers and say a quick prayer while clicking the submit button, others prefer a full ritual and blood sacrifice. Use trial and error to find what works for you.

Comment: Fairly, This question is appropriate for [academia.stackexchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Tao has some advice on his blog which you might wish to read https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko the point of asking on academia.SE is that it attracts answers that are suitable for a range of fields, and one can compare and contrast them. For applied maths and stats, the answers can sometimes be different to pure maths, being influenced by their areas of application and we don't have a wholly representative sample here.

Answer (score 19):

First of all, upload to the arxiv. Then you can write to the experts you know, and inform them that you uploaded your new paper. Then wait a little to give them opportunity to send you comments. If there is a possibility, give seminar/conference talks, but it is not necessary to do this before you send it
to a journal.

Edit. Posting the paper in the arxiv is really the most important step. See the comment of Timothy Chow for many reasons of this. From the point of view of
dissemination of the result, it is more important than publishing it in a journal. Some people who do not care about grants and promotions even do not bother to send their results to journals.

Comment: Just to elaborate a bit on the first point: Uploading to the arXiv does a few things. It establishes priority, in case someone else comes up with the same ideas almost simultaneously. If you give a talk, anyone who is interested in your work will want to see your paper, and it is convenient if the paper is already on the arXiv. Lots of people watch the arXiv, so you may get some very quick feedback from people who you might not have expected to have any interest in your paper; this is almost always a good thing.

Comment: (continued) There is just one possible downside I am aware of, which is that you effectively forgo the possibility of double-blind refereeing if you upload to the arXiv. For most people, though, the advantages of posting to the arXiv outweigh this disadvantage.

Comment: @Tomothy Chow: according to my experience as an author and as a referee, double blind refereeing is an extremely rare practice.

Comment: In my experience, posting on the arXiv gives you very little feedback.  You are much more likely to get helpful feedback by emailing a draft to a few friends and experts in the field.  On many occassions, I've also gotten helpful feedback from referee reports, in some cases saving me from embarrassing (fixable) mistakes; posting on the arXiv cannot be undone.  Further, contrary to the idea that it establishes priority, I've actually seen a few results "scooped", because they were available on the arXiv and someone found stronger results and published those extensions quickly. Also...

Comment: the papers on the arXiv are not always trustworthy, not having gone through any refereeing.  Many mathematicians do not trust papers on the arXiv to the same level as papers in good (reputable) journals.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko My experience with double blind refereeing is similar to yours, but in the last year or two, I've twice been asked to referee a paper with the names of the author(s) stripped. It seems to be on the rise. Regarding Pace Nielsen's comments, yes, sometimes that kind of "scooping" happens, but I've also been in a situation where if my coauthor and I had waited a month, we would not have been the first past the post. I think that for most people it's better to post to the arXiv sooner rather than later. If someone quickly builds on my work, I consider that a good thing.

Comment: As for arXiv articles not being trustworthy, that seems to be an entirely orthogonal question that you're addressing. Putting a paper on the arXiv does not preclude you from publishing in a journal. Surely that goes without saying? Unless you're saying that if you're "scooped" in the way that you say then people won't give you credit? I personally find such an attitude overly paranoid and I don't recommend living life that way.

Comment: @TimothyChow Some of these issues can also depend on the field you work in.  In my field, if two people come up with similar results, usually they combine forces rather than worry about priority.  My point about "scooping" is that some people post to the arXiv without having given themselves enough time to consider extensions, corollaries, etc..., or to get basic feedback. Usually these people are early in their careers, and so such scooping can be much more damaging to them.  Moreover, you can always post to the arXiv *after* the paper is accepted, and so the good...

Comment: effects from people writing on your material can still happen.  Regarding paranoia, I've found it is usually the people who are not willing to trust the refereeing system, and need to establish "priority", who suffer from that.  (And, subsequently, are actually *more* likely to be scooped.)

Comment: @TimothyChow My point about trustworthyness is that the arXiv just isn't a place to attract the dedicated attention of experts, except in extraordinary cases. You are more likely to attract attention to your work by getting it in a good journal, and emailing it to trusted friends and experts who are interested in similar problems.  (And from the other direction, if someone were to ask whether it is better to check the arXiv every day, or to subscribe to emails from the top journals of your field to see what's being published, I'd suggest the latter.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen Well, I agree that releasing a paper when it's half-baked is a bad idea, but that's true of publishing as well, not just the arXiv. And sure, you're more likely to get attention by getting it in a good journal and contacting people directly, but that's again a false dichotomy. But what I most disagree with is your last sentence. If I were to rely on journals rather than the arXiv, I'd be two or three years behind the times.

Comment: @TimothyChow First, I'm glad we agree that releasing a half-baked paper is a bad idea.  For a first-time publisher, like the person who asked the question, this issue should be raised before blindly telling them to post to the arXiv.  Second, I explicity mentioned that one could also publish to the arXiv at the appropriate time.  There is no dichotomy.  For a first-time publisher such timing is difficult to determine without feedback from trusted sources.  Finally, my experience (in my field) is opposite yours.  Papers in my area rarely appear on the arXiv, *many* of the ones that...

Comment: do appear are absolute junk.  The number of papers published in reputable journal *far* outstrips the number that appear on the arXiv, by orders of magnitude.  (Although, the truly groundbreaking papers may show up on arXiv.)  Papers in my area don't usually take multiple years to be refereed (only about 3-6 months, perhaps 1 year in extreme cases).  But most importantly, I wasn't saying one should ignore the arXiv.  Just that it is one of *many* tools, and that it should be approached with extra caution by a first-time publisher.

Comment: @PaceNielsen In my field, what I heard is almost always first submitting to arXiv. I wonder in your case what happens if one submits the paper A to a journal without first submitting to arXiv, and another comes up with similar results and ideas in the same time, finishing the paper B, and submitting it to arXiv, and then the paper A gets rejected? It seems that the paper A cannot be published anymore since the paper B already appeared on arXiv and taking credits?

Comment: @Z.M If you are working on a problem that has been in the literature for a decade or more, such a scenario is less likely. But depending on the types of problems you work on, and the kind of progress being made in your area, it *might* be the right thing to post to the arXiv (once you have done proofreading, gotten some preliminary feedback, etc...) before submitting to a journal. My point has always been that the *first step* is to follow Carlo Beenaker's counsel, as well as Christopher Drupieski's counsel. After that, worry about arXiv vs. journal.

Comment: @Z.M BTW. suppose that you have posted a preprint to the arXiv, and the next day another mathematician sends you a copy of their preprint, which covers much of the same material. You're told that their paper has been under review for a year, and they expect a report soon. Would you insist on having priority because you made your work publicly available first?

Comment: @Pace Nielsen: yes. When the first photographs from the James Webb telescope arrived, there was a competition to publish them, and the first arxiv publication was ahead of the second one from a competing group by several seconds:-)

Comment: @PaceNielsen It would depend on more factors. For example, suppose that you are a PhD student in this situation, you are going to find postdoc positions soon, and this is the only paper that you have produced so far (this happens to some PhD students — maybe you judge them being "too incompetent"), then the failure of not being published is fatal in the sense that you probably have to leave academia. Note also that, since another (presumably senior) mathematician did not submit to arXiv, you unconsciously worked out something "in vain", which seems disastrous for PhD students.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko If you are arguing that one paper has more value than another, based merely on the fact that one was submitted to the arXiv a few seconds before the other, then I strongly disagree.  If you are arguing that this establishes priority, I also strongly disagree.  (Given how long it takes to write a paper, it is obvious that these results are independent of one another.)  Moreover, I'd argue that not only in math, but in all science, we should work to get away from such posturing.

Comment: @Z.M Your guess about judging was unnecessary and incorrect. Moving on, I don't think it would do any good for a new PhD student in the situation I raised to assert priority. However, it would be a good idea for the student to explain to the senior mathematician the situation (including a need for publications to get a job), and ask to join forces. Moreover, with good advising, it needn't be disastrous for new PhDs to learn how to deal with such situations. (When I was writing my own thesis, a paper was published on the same topic, claiming to have solved the problem I was working on.)

Answer (score 16):

First of all, proofread it several times. Remember that every minor mistake that will take you five minutes to correct may perplex the reader for several hours, so aim at minimizing the community time, not just your own time.

Second, check that all references that you use in an essential way are easily accessible and contain full proofs, not just further references to endless "trees of knowledge". Remember that the full length of your paper is the sum of the pages in the main text, the texts you refer to, the texts the texts you refer to refer to, and so on until you reach some "common knowledge" layer (what exactly constitutes it depends on whom you are writing for, but don't aim just at "experts").

Third, show it to some knowledgeable people you trust and discuss with them both the content and the readability. You may get some useful feedback on both accounts.

Then, if everything looks good, place it on arXiv and send the link to the people who you believe may be interested. Meanwhile think of where you would like submit it. Once you have made your choice, submit following the chosen journal procedure (you can usually find all the requirements, style files, etc. on the journal webpage).

Once you get a referee report, see what you agree with and what you disagree with. Remember 2 things. First, the referees see your paper with the "reader eyes" as opposed to "author eyes" you see it with, so if they stumble somewhere and say that they would appreciate a clarification, then, most likely, some other readers will appreciate it too even if it looks crystal clear to you. Second, the referees are not all-powerful and omniscient gods, so it is totally OK to disagree with them both about mathematics and about stylistic issues. If you think that some referee suggestion is totally outlandish or stems from complete misunderstanding of what was written, you are by no means obliged to follow it. Just explain in the letter to the editor why you think so.

Once you get the galley proofs, go over them and compare with the submitted text. Check that all technical editor corrections make sense (usually they are minor, but even a minor change can alter the meaning of a sentence sometimes). If you are happy with everything, that's the end: the paper is out for publication and you do not need to do anything else. If not, report the needed corrections to the editor. Usually they just accept them at that stage.

That's the full process from the beginning to the end as I see it.

Comment: I'd only add that for step #4 (putting it on the arXiv), you would also want to follow the advice from step #3 and first talk to knowledgeable people you trust.  There are sometimes reasons not to post a paper to the arXiv immediately; such as if you are still working on extensions of the result for a second paper that isn't yet finished (and you wouldn't want that work scooped), etc...